# Access Unity "In App Purchasing" products

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm using In App Purchasing in my Unity project, and I need to access my products data (like quantity or price) via script. I know that this data can be accessed with ProductDefinition class, but I still need to get those definitions somewhere.

I've tried to access products via different UnityEngine.Purchasing classes, but didn't find anything there. I've also tried to set both Product and ProductDefinition through Inspector, but they simply don't appear there.